# How to setup multicloud architecture in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: azure, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a peer in google cloud platform. I have to join that peer to the channel in azure network.

What I tried:

Generated crypto-materials for new peer using azure network webclient and used that crypto-config materials in all the peers, orderer and webclient in azure and also in the new peer I have in google cloud. But after that new peer can join the channel of azure but could not install instantiate the chaincodes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two recommended approaches to setting up Hyperledger Fabric Network on Azure. You can use the Hyperledger Fabric template available in the Azure Marketplace to launch your environment on Azure or you can take the hard way and manually commission VM Instances. Using the template is obviously a faster solution. It is also a better solution. If you were to manually set up your environment, you would have to consider 2 cases — using multiple VM instances (usually in a production environment) or a single VM (for a development environment).

In the second case, you would have to set up the communication rules between VM instances if you are using multiple ones. You would have to download and install the Fabric SDKs and configure the channels and peers and every other facet of a typical Hyperledger Fabric network. While that is easy to do for single, Dev mode VM instance, things get really complicated when you have to consider multiple running instances. Hence, it is better to use the Hyperledger Fabric Template to set up your Fabric environment on Azure.

In either approach, Fabric Network generates a channel configuration. This step generates a new channel configuration block that includes the new member belonging to the peer node in GCP. A configuration block is similar to the genesis block, defining the members and policies for a channel. In fact, you can consider a configuration block to be the genesis block plus the delta of configuration changes that have occurred since the channel was created.

Azure VM Fabric Network can shares the genesis block for the channel with Peer Node in GCP. Before the peer node in GCP joins the channel, it must be able to connect to the ordering service. It obtains the ordering service endpoint from the channel genesis block.

If you are facing issues in the GCP peer node, please confirm that the peer node is receiving blocks on the channel, you install chain code. You then run a query against the local ledger on the peer. After installing the chain code, the peer node in GCP can run queries against its own world state database.